# Ubuntu installer can't find my internal drive

Tags: system-installation, uefi, asus, drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on an Asus VivoBook Flip 12 TP202NA.
It currently has a Windows install that I want to get rid of (no dual boot).

At partition step the installer is not able to find my internal drive, only the USB stick on which I ran the installer.

I have tried with different kind of live USB (systemrescuecd, live gparted, archlinux) but I can't find any device, every time I only see the USB stick.

The only piece of error I got is in the dmesg:

```
mmc0: switch to bus width for hs400 failed, err:-84
mmc0: error -84 whilst initialising MMC card
```

EDIT:
Thanks to oldfred suggestion I tried with lubuntu and the installer luckily did found the internal emmc and installed lubuntu on it the first time I ran it.

But now I can't boot on it(end up on an initramfs shell) and I can't even reinstall lubuntu.
I keep seeing those errors on the mmc... There is definitively something bad with that mmc (SanDisk DF4032 749B806) but I can't figure out what.

I've checked the BIOS version and it is up to date (version 210)

EDIT2:
Bug is related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1818407

Comment: Many Asus have needed UEFI updates. Is yours the most current version? Since lightweight system, you may want Lubuntu, Budgie or Mate as a lightweight flavor. Many Asus also need boot parameter `pci=nomsi`

Comment: Thanks for the lubuntu suggestion. It turns out the first time I ran the installer lubuntu somehow found the internal drive (which is an emmc) and successfully installed the system.

But now I can't boot nor re install lubuntu, it keeps failing at mmc detection with the same error
mmc0: switch to bus width fir hs400 failed, err:-84
mmc0: error -84 whilst initialising MMC card

It give up at boot and I land on an initramfs shell

There is definitively something fishy with that emmc (SanDisk DF4032 749B806)

BIOS is up to date with a version 210

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking the bios for any settings that may be keeping the drive from being visible. I was having this issue on a Dell laptop with an NVME drive and I had to enter into the bios and "reset to factory defaults" before the drive would appear.

I would also check to see if there are any bios/UEFI updates available and install them as "oldfred" mentioned in the comment above.